# how to completely reset gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Hello Is there a way to completely reset gnuplot, ie taking gnuplot in the **same** state as just after launching it ? Reset does not kill the variables nor the functions, undefine cannot be used as "undefine *" since the first character has to be a letter. 
Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

```
gnuplot> x=1
gnuplot> print x
1
gnuplot> reset session
gnuplot> print x
     undefined variable: x
```

Comment: This does not reset the canvas size for the output terminal I am using. Is there any way to do a 'harder' reset?

Comment: @Mead hmm, the documentation mentions that, e.g., `set term`, `set output`, `set fit`, etc. are not affected by `reset`. An alternative could be perhaps to use user-defined variables for the settings of interest and then recover it manually after doing `reset session`...