# Total reset of a gnuplot session

Tags: gnuplot

I would like a way to completely reset a `gnuplot` session from within `gnuplot`; exactly equivalent to exiting and restarting.

The commands `reset` or `reset session` (http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/reset.html) are not sufficient, since some options that were set before linger after either command (e.g., `set term`, `set output`, ...).

Note that the solution to [how to completely reset gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468979/how-to-completely-reset-gnuplot) is not sufficient for my purposes.

For context, the problem I am having is that I often use the same terminal session to execute many different `gnuplot` scripts to make many different plots. For some of those plots I want to simply use default options, while for others I prefer to be more specific. If I run one of the more "specific" scripts before I run one of the "default" scripts many of the "specific" settings are applied to the "default" plot, even when each script begins with a `reset session` command. My current solution is to manually restart gnuplot, which is a bit annoying.

The following minimal script illustrates an example of the problem: After running both the `reset` and `reset session` commands the terminal is not reset to whatever the default is. Here by 'default' I mean whatever terminal loads up when it starts, in my case `qt`. Note that the terminal type is just one example of a number of things that linger after the `reset` commands. I want some way of restoring `gnuplot` to exactly the state it starts in.

```
show terminal

set terminal pdfcairo

show terminal

reset
reset session

show terminal
```

Comment: Could you show us a minimal code that reproduces the situation as an example?

Comment: @binzo I have added some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the hard reset you mention is provided by gnuplot.
As your example shows, it seems to be difficult to do an exact reset with the `reset session`.

As a workaround, you might try the following method using an initialization script.
`help reset` says,

> The following are *not* affected by `reset`:
> `set term` `set output` `set loadpath` `set linetype` `set fit`
> `set encoding` `set decimalsign` `set locale` `set psdir`
> `set overflow` `set multiplot`

And, `help reset session` mentions also like this,

> `reset session` deletes any user-defined variables and functions, restores
> default settings, and then re-executes the system-wide gnuplotrc initialization
> file and any private $HOME/.gnuplot or $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gnuplot/gnuplotrc
> preferences file.  See `initialization`.

According to this behavior, I recommend that you write the default settings you need in the initialization file "$HOME/.gnuplot" that will be called when you do `reset session`.

Here are the steps to do so:

(1) Invoke `gnuplot` with the `-d` option.

(2) Run command `save "settings.plt"` to save the current settings to "settings.plt".

(3) Extract the necessary settings from the contents of "settings.plt".

Here is the case in my environment (it may be different in yours).

```
set terminal x11  nopersist enhanced
set output
set loadpath 
set fit brief errorvariables nocovariancevariables errorscaling prescale nowrap v5
set encoding default
unset decimalsign
set locale "C"
set psdir
```

The `save` command does not write out the configuration of the linetype, it needs to be examined separately.

(4) Run command `show linetype` to find out the default settings of the linetype.

```
    linetype 1,  linecolor rgb "red"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 1 pointsize default
    linetype 2,  linecolor rgb "#009e73"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 2 pointsize default
    linetype 3,  linecolor rgb "#56b4e9"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 3 pointsize default
    linetype 4,  linecolor rgb "#e69f00"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 4 pointsize default
    linetype 5,  linecolor rgb "#f0e442"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 5 pointsize default
    linetype 6,  linecolor rgb "#0072b2"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 6 pointsize default
    linetype 7,  linecolor rgb "#e51e10"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 7 pointsize default
    linetype 8,  linecolor rgb "black"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 8 pointsize default
    Linetypes repeat every 8 unless explicitly defined
```

See `help linetype` for more information on how to write it.

(5) Write them in "$HOME/.gnuplot".

Comment: In the absence of an official solution I think this is the best you can do. I actually wrote the contents of your `settings.plt` into a script that I can then run when I like, but the effect is the same.